# How to the enlarge the font size of a journal paper

Tags: publications, formatting

I’m a low-vision person. I want to print research papers to read. But the font size is very small for me. Is there any way to make it bigger and print it?

Comment: It would be up to the publisher to have a large print version.

Comment: Some publishers (e.g. IEEE) offer a HTML version of the paper on their website where you can change the font size freely.

Comment: What field are these papers in?

Comment: As it stands, there is little about this question that is specific to academia (I will write an answer about the only exception I can think of). I suggest that you first ask this question for PDFs and webpages in general on [su], [ubuntu.se], [softwarerecs.se], or similar.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft What *is* specific to academia is the fact that academic papers continue to be published only in non-accessible formats. This is one of many ways in which academia tends to be a hostile environment for people with disabilities.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: That’s (sadly) not specific to academia. I regularly encounter user manuals, legal material, and similar stuff that are only available in a ready-to-print PDF. Even if it were, we are not the right group experts to solve this problem (or at least most aspects of it).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - While I agree OP may get helpful advice at some other SE sites, I am bothered by the closure.  Disability accommodation in academia should be something everyone in academia should be looking to learn more about -- understanding better what the needs are, and thinking about solutions and workarounds.

Comment: In the U.S. you can borrow a CCTV from your local office that supports people with disabilities, including low vision.  You put the printed page or the journal or book on the platen and turn a knob to control the magnification level.  You may need to move the page up and down as you go.  If you are a student, there would be reasonable accommodations, provided in the U.S. as a 504 Plan.  I'd also encourage you to write to the authors for an electronic format that is easier to blow up on your computer monitor.

Answer (score 2):

If the paper is in PDF (the standard) you can print using the Poster option. You will need to print the page in a bigger size, to make it fit in multiple pages.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/basic-pdf-printing-tasks.html

You can try to convert the PDF to word and enlarge the font before printing, but many don't convert well.

https://smallpdf.com/pt/pdf-para-word

Comment: pdf to word is never an option if the paper contains formula or graph or equation, it deforms completely

Answer (score 2):

If the paper in question has been submitted to the Arxiv as a LaTeX source, you can download its source (*other formats* in the sidepanel → *source*), change the font size to your liking, compile the result and print it. This also applies to other aspects affecting readability such as the font itself, the number of columns, and the image size.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that has not been suggested yet is **printing to A3 paper**, which makes the document larger by a factor 1.414. This is similar to the poster option mentioned in Cochise's answer.

Comment: Perhaps a low-vison person will find it worth the expense to buy a printer that handles such larger-than-normal paper sizes.

Comment: @GEdgar Universities often have A3 printers, in my experience.

Comment: @GEdgar This kind of misses the point. Compiled PDFs are not an accessible format for a lot of disabilities, not just low vision/large print.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning OP asked about printing and too small font size. If you are interested in other disabilities, it's a different question.